# How to flatten my sample object in Typescript using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to flatten input json and merge objects with the same key. Expected object has a structure like below example:

```
{
  "error": {
     "group1": {
         "mapping":
             [{"0": "mapping1"},
              {"1": "mapping1"}],
         "other": 
             [{"0": "other0"}]
    },
    "group2": {
         "mapping": 
             [{"0": "mapping2"},
              {"1": "mapping2"}]

    }
  }
}
```

so I want to get rid of groups and remain only types which are children of groups. The output should be:

```
{
  "error": {
      "mapping":
        [{"0": "mapping1"},
         {"1": "mapping1"},
         {"0": "mapping2"},
         {"1": "mapping2"}]
      "other": 
        [{"0": "other0"}]
  }
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript, here's my code, I believe it can be done a lot better:

```
function flattenReport(obj) {
    var reports = Object.keys(obj.error)
        for (report in reports) {
            var pos = obj.error[reports[report]]
            var types = Object.keys(pos)
            for (type in types) {
                var pos1 = pos[types[type]]
                var elements = Object.keys(pos1)
                for (element in elements) {
                    if (types[type] in obj.error) {
                        obj.error[types[type]].push(pos1[element])
                }
                else {
                    obj.error[types[type]] = []
                    obj.error[types[type]].push(pos1[element])
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return obj
}
```

I think Lodash would help shorten this up

edit:I forgot about deleting the groups at the end of my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash could solve the problem simply:

```js
let x= {
  "error": {
     "group1": {
         "mapping":
             [{"0": "mapping1"},
              {"1": "mapping1"}],
         "other": 
             [{"0": "other0"}]
    },
    "group2": {
         "mapping": 
             [{"0": "mapping2"},
              {"1": "mapping2"}]

    }
  }
}

let result = {"error":
     _.mergeWith({},..._.map(x['error'],v=>v),(o, s)=>(o||[]).concat(s))
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for lodash, this is pretty simple to accomplish with a single nested loop. Because you don't want to do anything with the value arrays except concatenate them together into the new array for that key, you can use `concat` instead of `push`:

```js
function flattenReport(initialObj) {
  const newGroupsObj = {};
  Object.values(initialObj.error).forEach((obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, arr]) => {
      newGroupsObj[key] = (newGroupsObj[key] || []).concat(arr);
    });
  });
  return { error: newGroupsObj };
}

const obj = {
  "error": {
    "group1": {
      "mapping": [{
          "0": "mapping1"
        },
        {
          "1": "mapping1"
        }
      ],
      "other": [{
        "0": "other0"
      }]
    },
    "group2": {
      "mapping": [{
          "0": "mapping2"
        },
        {
          "1": "mapping2"
        }
      ]

    }
  }
};

console.log(flattenReport(obj));
```